# C++ Is there a stack frame for the constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, compilation

In C++, when a function is called, a new stack frame is added to the call stack, containing its parameters and local variables (and other things).  Does this also happen when an object constructor is called?
If so, does this change when the constructor uses an initialization list? What is the structure of this stack frame? Does it contain the object's member variables (which must be in the heap after the execution of the constructor)?

Comment: The object's members *must* be in the heap? No. When you construct an object with automatic storage duration it stays on the stack just fine.

Comment: A constructor call is still a method call, so a stack frame is governed by the compiler settings for any function call.  Some compilers allow stack frames to be disabled or optimized away.

Comment: It's not specified as part of the language that a stack frame is created, nor its structure if it is. It's dependent on the compiler / ABI and may not necessarily be predictable.

Comment: Constructors are not virtual, so plenty of opportunity for the code optimizer to get them inlined.  This should of course not concern you.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to think constructor especially. It's just a kind of function - for example, This C++ code is

```
class Test
{
private:
    int m_a;
public:
    Test() : m_a(0) { puts("Test::Test()"); }
    explicit Test(int i) : m_a(i) { puts("Test::Test(int)"); }
    void f(char c) { puts("Test::f(char)"); }
    ~Test() { puts("Test::~Test()");
};

int main()
{
    Test t1;
    Test t2(3);

    t1.f('a');
}
```

almost similar to

```
struct Test
{
    int m_a;
};

void Test__ctor_0(Test *thiz) { thiz->m_a = 0; puts("Test::Test()"); }
void Test__ctor_1(Test *thiz, int i) { thiz->m_a = i; puts("Test::Test(int)"); }
void Test__f(Test *thiz, char c) { puts("Test::f(char)"); }
void Test__dtor_(Test *thiz) { puts("Test::~Test()"); }

int main()
{
    struct Test t1;
    Test__ctor_0(&t1);

    struct Test t2;
    Test__ctor_1(&t2, 3);

    Test__f(&t1, 'a');

    Test__dtor_(&t1);
    Test__dtor_(&t2);
}
```

this C code.

Of course, the stack frame can be created when you call ctor, if it's not inlined or compiler optimizes call not to create stack frame to reduce the decrease of performance.

(In cdecl of x86, `this` pointer is sent through `ecx` register, unlike other parameter. So if the constructor don't use any local variables and don't have any additional parameters, stack frame could be not created.)

Answer (score 1):

Construction is handled like any other method call.

If it doesn't get inlined by the optimizer, a stack frame will be created holding an implicit "this" pointer and all passed-in parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Most architectures' ABIs call member functions by putting the `this`-pointer into a specific register, or by pushing it onto the stack at a particular position. Constructors are a little unusual language-wise, but from the point of view of the ABI they follow this pattern.

In general, the `this`-pointer is treated as an implicit first argument to the function. For instance, under the normal x86 calling convention, a pointer to the object is at the "bottom" (memory-order-wise) of the stack. The member variables themselves aren't on the stack; that wouldn't make any sense, because the constructor (as with other member functions) might need to write to those variables, and those writes would need to affect the "real" copy of the object. Hence pushing a pointer to them instead.

Answer (score 0):

Object construction involves more than just the execution of constructor body. First off, all the base subobjects and member subobjects are initialized, and only *then* does the contructor body run. So when a particular constructor is selected for object construction, the subobject constructors run first, and their arguments are given by the original constructor's initializer list. Afterwards, the constructor body runs, more or less like a normal function, with parameters populated from the constructor arguments.